# Inequalities (AMGM & Cauchy Schwarz)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Let $ x, y, z \geq 0 $ such that $x+y+z=1$. Find the maximum value of
>   $$x (x+y)^2 (y+z)^3 (z+x)^4.$$

Hi recently I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time, and I would appreciate some help/hints on how to approach this inequality.

Also, would be good if the approaches were based on AM-GM or Cauchy Schwarz.

Thanks!

Comment: We usually want one question per question here. It makes things easier for everyone.

Comment: Also if possible please learn to use latex on the site. It's very simple and can make your posts look much better. :)

Comment: @Lazy Lee oh ok I wasn't aware we could use latex here

Comment: Ok edited the question

Comment: I think this question asked right. I think to close this topic is not necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! We can solve this problem by AM-GM.

Indeed, 
$$x(x+y)^2 (y+z)^3 (z+x)^4=\frac{2x(2x+2y)^2(2y+2z)^3(z+x)^4}{64}\leq$$
$$\leq\frac{1}{64}\left(\frac{2x+2(2x+2y)+3(2y+2z)+4(z+x)}{10}\right)^{10}=\frac{1}{64}.$$
The equality occurs for $x=\frac{1}{2}$,$y=0$ and $z=\frac{1}{2}$, which says that the answer is $\frac{1}{64}.$

Done!

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't see this at first but now I understand.

Comment: @Russell Ng You are welcome!